# How do I ignore certain tags in lxml before parsing it?

Tags: python, regex, lxml

I am using lxml to parse some xml. Some of the tags have malformed html that cause lxml to throw errors. We would like to just skip over "Tag1" and be able to parse the rest of the doc. We have tried the following but still get an error "lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: b":

```
s = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><myroot><Tag1><b>this is some malformed</Tag1><Tag2>We will continue on</Tag2></myroot>'
xml = etree.fromstring(s)
etree.strip_elements(xml, 'Tag1')
print xml.find('.//Tag2').text
```

The error occurs because we parse the document then try to ignore Tag1. Is there a way to ignore Tag1 before we parse the document in lxml?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html) which can parse broken html (xml).

```
import bs4
s = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><myroot><Tag1><b>this is some malformed</Tag1><Tag2>We will continue on</Tag2></myroot>'
root=bs4.BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
print root.find('tag2').text #-> We will continue on
```

Answer (score 1):

Use lxml.html.fromstring() instead. It is more forgiving of HTML-isms. The html version reads your sample without error.